# Using jGestures with jQuery "on" events

Tags: jquery, mobile, gesture, jgestures

I have a number of dynamically-generated divs that need to be tapped. For mouse-oriented devices, I usually do this:

```
$("#wrap").on("click", 'div', function() { console.log("clicked!"); });
```

I have noticed a major sensitivity speed-up on mobiles when using jGestures custom events, which work perfectly when used this way:

```
$("#wrap").bind('tapone', function() { console.log("tapped!"); });
```

However, I cannot use `tapone` with the jQuery `.on` events like this:

```
$("#wrap").on("tapone", 'div', function() { console.log("tapped!"); });
```

Does anyone know a way of getting around this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build your own delegation, if you had this:

```
$("#wrap").on('click', '#myID', function() { console.log("clicked!"); });
```

All it really does is:

```
$("#wrap").on('click', function(e) { 
    if ( e.target.id == 'myID' )
        console.log("clicked!"); 
});
```

So for your custom events you could do:

```
$("#wrap").on("tapone", function(e) {
    if ( e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'div' )
        console.log("tapped!"); 
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Jv52C/)

Comment: @johnsmith - `e.target.getAttribute('name')`

Comment: actually... it doesn't work! in your fiddle, it works because you are using "click" - which does work on me as well. but I am looking for the jgesture "tapone"

Comment: I realize that, but if that event works the way events should work, it has an event.target you can compare to create delegated functionality by targeting a non dynamic parent, just like in the example.

Comment: ok, it doesn't. apparenty i need to modify something in jgesture. because what it basically does is that the event returned is the wrapper div and not the actual child

Comment: @johnsmith - yeah, that would be a problem, and is probably why jQuery's event delagation does'nt work either. The only way to fix that would be to change the plugin to return the target and not the wrapper.

Comment: cool. just add in your answer that it's undoable without modifying the plugin, so I mark your answer as correct :)